How to declare a type based on the property value of an object in an array of objects
If the array has no optional attributes or is not nested, then I can use the const type to get the union type I need, but when the original array has nested and optional attributes, I don’t know what to do.
// I have an array structure like this
const data = [
    {
        key: 'name',
        desc: 'desc...'
    }, {
        key: 'password',
        desc: 'desc'
    }, {
        key: 'balabala',
        desc: 'bb.'
    }
] as const

type DataKey = typeof data[number]['key']

const fn = (key: DataKey) {
    switch (key) {
        // Here the key can be inferred to be name | password | balabala
        case 'name':
            break
    }
}

But when data is nested, how to get the nested key attribute, especially when the nested attribute is optional
type Deep = {key: string, desc: string, child?: Deep[]}
const dataDeep: Deep[] = [
    {
        key: 'name',
        desc: 'desc...'
    }, {
        key: 'password',
        desc: 'desc'
    }, {
        key: 'balabala',
        desc: 'bb.',
        child: [{
            key: 'deep',
            desc: 'deep'
        }]
    }
]
// Here we hope that the key can be inferred name | password | balabala | deep


As written you can't - that information isn't available, the type of dataDeep is simply Deep[], so any (typeof dataDeep)[number]["key"] (let alone the recursive case) is just string. You'd have to start by preserving that, e.g.: https://tsplay.dev/WJPy6N.

You will still need to use as const (or probably better, satisfies …). What needs to change is rather the typeof data[number]['key'] part, now extended by typeof data[number]['child'][number]['key'] (… and further, if you want arbitrary recursion, with another helper type).

If you define dataDeep as const, you can recurse through it's keys. You can't extract the keys from something typed Deep[], as that will always be string.
const dataDeep = [
    {
        key: 'name',
        desc: 'desc...'
    }, {
        key: 'password',
        desc: 'desc'
    }, {
        key: 'balabala',
        desc: 'bb.',
        child: [{
            key: 'deep',
            desc: 'deep',
            child: [{
                key: 'deeper',
                desc: 'deeper...'
            }]
        }]
    }
] as const satisfies Deep[];

type DeepKeys<T extends Deep> = T extends {} ? T["key"] | (T["child"] extends {} ? DeepKeys<T["child"][number]> : never) : never;

type DataNames = DeepKeys<(typeof dataDeep)[number]>;
  // "name" | "password" | "balabala" | "deep" | "deeper"

Playground link

It's very helpfull, thanks
